# How to interpret the cumulative average?

Tags: descriptive-statistics, mean

I have calculated the cumulative average of Y as function of X. As far as I know, the cumulative average highlights the "low-frequency trend" of a variable as a function of another variable.

I am struggling trying to interpret the evolution of the cumulative average with X. You find the plot as an attachment.
If I am correct, during the initial phase, the cumulative average varies more (because of the few data). At a later stage, it reaches the long run trend which, in this case, is a monotonic decrease of the cumulative average as X increases.
Is this interpretation correct?

[image: Cumulative average of Y as function of X]

Comment: How much data do you have?

Comment: I think basically that *description* of the plot is correct, but a couple of things give me pause.  The first is that the decrease is not strictly monotonic, but only generally so.  The second is that your horizontal axis appears to be highly nonlinear, perhaps on a log scale, which means an awful lot of data (and potentially variation) lurk at the extreme right hand side.  You might find it instructive to compute your running mean *in reverse* to see how it behaves.  (@Michael: Doesn't the plot answer your question?)

Comment: @whuber You make great points but where is the information on the sample size.

Comment: @Michael The number of unique dots in the plot is the data size.  Although that number cannot be determined, it obviously is large--one can make out about a hundred distinct points plus a mass that must be formed of far more.  Moreover, from the magnitudes of the local oscillations in height--which should be inversely proportional to the root sample size--we can deduce that there are around 800 to 8,000 values shown here.

Comment: I have almost 13000 data points, indeed.    @whuber You're correct. The important thing is that I do not make any mistake when I say that a decreasing trend is the "low-frequency" trend the cumulative average tends to. Actually, in the plot the x-axis is in the reverse order and the cumulative average has been calculated for x-values in reverse order. The reason is that I have very few data points for high x and a lot of data for low values of x. The plot should highlight the influence of the first.